# IIS rewrite rendering script, css and image URLs incorrectly

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a rewrite rule in my `web.config` like this:

```
<rules>    
    <rule name="products" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"  >

      <match url="^products/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />

      <action type="Rewrite" url="test_produit.aspx?code_prod={R:1}&amp;lib_prod={R:2}" />

      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(ashx|axd|css|gif|png|jpg|svg|jpeg|js|flv|f4v)$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>

    </rule>
</rules>
```

I want to have url like this :

> http://www.test.com/products/1502/nice-car/

The problem is that the links for my Javascript, CSS and images are broken and are rendered as:

> http://www.test.com/products/1502/nice-car/css/...

or

> http://www.test.com/products/1502/nice-car/js/...

...instead of rendering as:

> http://www.test.com/css/...
> or
> http://www.test.com/js/...

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: In other words, you don’t want these JS/CSS URL to match the URL rules, is that correct? Do your conditions work? Theoretically, it has already ruled out the CSS/JS file, it will not trigger the URL rewrite rules. why does it still happen?